# How to clear the JXDatePicker field

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, datepicker, swingx

I am developing a simple desktop application
 with Java and NetBeans 7
I have a textfield and a textarea as well as a jxdatepicker
I have a CLEAR button that is suppose to clear the fields when needed

I use the

```
jtextfield.setText("") and 
  jtextArea.setText("")
```

to clear the textfield and textarea as indicated.
but my problem is that how do I clear the date picker 
to present a clean field when the clear button is clicked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

basically:

```
picker.setDate(null);
```

Addendum:

digging into the internals of the picker and setting the text of its editor is *wrong* because the text is only updated in the editor but not committed to the underlying model:

```
picker.getEditor().setText("");
System.out.println(picker.getDate());

// output
Thu Feb 28 00:00:00 CET 2013 

// output after nulling the date with the appropriate api
null
```

Comment: Are you really 93 years old? 0_o. Your profile shows your `age = 93`.

Comment: @HarryJoy it wouldn't take my real 103 <g>

Answer (score 0):

1.Set property like this.
    datePicker.getModel().setValue(null);;